# How to access aws system manager keys in aws amplify?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-ssm

I need to make it possible to access in a secure way to sentive keys on my next js amplify app.

I have tried a lot of approaches, but the goal here is not to hardcode the variables or the accounts keys in the code to make it work, I even try to invoke the keys in the amplify.yml file so I can used it by typing process.env.

```
version: 1
env:
  variables:
    secrets:
      # SECRET_KEY_NAME defined in secrets manager
        MY_SECRET_KEY: SECRET_KEY_NAME 
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - export MY_SECRET_VALUE=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ${env.MY_SECRET_KEY} --query SecretString --output text)
        - echo "MY_SECRET_KEY=${MY_SECRET_VALUE}" >> .env
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

But after deploying I get an xml error (This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.)In the deployed app url.

Nothing makes sense have anyone ever done this, if so; how?

Comment: Where would you need the keys? You can create environment variables for each lambda function via the `CLI`, or you can create custom AWS CDK stack to use infrastructure-as-code for a secrets manager and then add the codes to the console.